# Inserting data using JSP (Eclipse) into database (XAMPP, MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, servlets

So I'm trying to register(insert) record from JSP form into database (XAMPP, MySQL). Details are as follows:

**register.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action = "RegisterController" method = "post">
        <input type = "text" name = "email" placeholder = "Your e-mail"><br><br>
        <input type = "text" name = "firstname" placeholder = "First name"><br><br>
        <input type = "text" name = "lastname" placeholder = "Last name"><br><br>
        <input type = "text" name = "address" placeholder = "Home address"><br><br>
        <input type = "text" name = "phone" placeholder = "Your phone number"><br><br>
        <input type = "password" name = "password"><br><br>
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Register">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**RegisterController.java**

```
package cms.com;

import java.io.IOException;


import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RegisterController
 */
public class RegisterController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RegisterController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try{

            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
            String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
            String address = request.getParameter("address");
            String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String sql = "insert into users(email,firstname,lastname,address,phone,password) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cms","root","");
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            pst.setString(1,email);
            pst.setString(2,firstname);
            pst.setString(3,lastname);
            pst.setString(4,address);
            pst.setString(5, phone);
            pst.setString(6, password);

            pst.executeUpdate();
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("You have successfully registered!");

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

}
```

So when I run on localhost and entered details, it only displayed an empty page and the table had no update whatsoever.Debugging shows no error as well as during runtime. I'm using Eclipse Luna with Dynamic Module 2.5 and Apache Tomcat 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Add [Mysql](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.mysql/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar.zip) jar in your project and you have to mapping  `RegisterController` file in Web.xml file (`WebContent\WEB-INF\Web.xml`)

and also check a path on 'form action' in `Register.jsp` and 'url-pattern' in `Web.xml` both must be same.